# Splice function to get rid of 6/7th of the entries in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm trying to understand where i'm going wrong here. say I have an array:

```
result = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

I want to get rid of every 6 entries in my array, leave the 7th there, and go one. In effect i'm hoping to get rid of 6/7th of the values in my array. I'm thinking splice() could be perfect for that, but somehow the code below doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Many thanks to you all!

```
function random_select ()
    {
      for(var i=0; i < result.length; i+7)
      {
        result.splice[i,6];

      }
    };
```

Comment: Couple of problems: (a) You are modifying the array while iterating over it from start to end. You'd have to iterate over it in *reverse order*. (b) You are never advancing the loop index. `i+7` should be `i += 7`. (c) `splice` is a function, which has to be called like `splice(x, y)` not `splice[x, y]`.

Comment: Change `i+1` to `i++`, and change `result.splice[i,6]` to `result.splice(i+1,6)`. Since the Array is mutated and reindexed, the current index becomes the next item after your `.splice()`. So instead we start the mutation on the next index, so all you need is to move beyond the current index to get to the next multiple of `7`. If you need to remove the `0`, add a `result.shift()` after the loop. *(Reformulation of my previous comments.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var result = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) result.splice(i, 6);
```

This will:

1. First remove `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and let `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]` be.
2. Next remove `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` and let `[13, 14, 15, 16]` be.
3. Finally remove `[13, 14, 15, 16]`.

Hence the result is `[6, 13]`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hey Aadit, this along Felix and Train's propositions did the work perfectly for me, thanks a bunch!